# Can bash commands time out between ampersands?

Tags: bash

I'm running a cron job to this effect, however, I noticed that the final command was not being reached.  Some of the commands genuinely take a long time however, maybe 20-30 minutes each, let's say.

```
cd /some_file_path/ && 
  wget [some url] -O dd.csv &&
  csvjoin --outer -c VendorStockCode,sku dd.csv dicker.csv > dd_joined.csv &&
  csvcut -c Vendor,VendorStockCode,StockDescription,PrimaryCategory,SecondaryCategory,TertiaryCategory,DealerEx,StockAvailable,overview,specs,multi_images dd_joined.csv > dd_joined_cut22.csv &&
  wget -q -O - [some url]
```

Yet the next day after triggering the cron job, the final command still hasn't been reached.

- Assuming all the commands are work individually in a finite time with a total execution time of less than a day, why wouldn't the entire command finish once a day has passed?
- Is this a timeout issue relating to the use of chained ampersands?
- Does anybody see an obvious logical flaw with the command chain above?

Comment: The `&&` is a logical AND. If any of the commands fail the pipeline looks for a logical OR `||`, a command separator `;`, or exits.  Likely one of your commands is exiting with non-zero.

Comment: If all the commands executed successfully when run individually, is that synonymous with all of them having a zero exit?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't guarantee they are doing so in your cron job.  using `wget` to remote servers could potentially fail for nearly infinite reasons.  Or the data returned could not be in valid csv format potentially causing your csv related commands to fail.  Or have you even checked the exit codes?  Maybe they are seemingly succeeding but exiting with non zero to indicate that something undesirable happened.

Answer (score 2):

Due the interdepencency of your commands it's very likely any network error caused by wget will cause a non-zero exit leading to a incomplete chain of events.

Since this a cron you're limited to what is possible, I suggest moving this logic to a simple bash script.

If you're fetching a lot of data you can use [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) to download it faster, but that depends if your source is dynamic or not.

A simple approach to solve would be force it to retry and catch it's exit signal

```
cd path/to

while [ 1 ]; do
    wget --retry-connrefused --waitretry=1 --read-timeout=20 --timeout=15 -t 0 -c [download link]
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then break; fi
done

csvjoin  ...
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow and let you know if it helps.  aria2 also sounds very interesting.  With the wget, there is is a long pause, and the download itself is 37MB, so maybe aria2 will help speed things up.

Comment: The loop here could be written as `while ! wget --retry-connrefused ... ; do true; done`. (or with `sleep 5` in place of `true` to not busyloop in case there's a problem that causes `wget` to return immediately.)